# Why TEXT column returns only 4096 bytes?

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm storing a long text with mssql_query();

And Using the field with datatype called 'text'.

I tried with different long strings by using str_repeat(), the page takes long time, but in the end submits the result.
When I retrieve the result however, I get only 4096 bytes nomatterwhat.
I tried to retrieve the value with management studio too, and it gets the same outcome.

It looks to me like a storing problem to me. Please advice something... I'm confused.

**EDIT** for these who asked, this is what I'm using:

```
function sql_escape($sql) { 
        /* De MagicQuotes */ 
    $fix_str        = stripslashes($sql); 
    $fix_str    = str_replace("'","''",$sql); 
    $fix_str     = str_replace("\0","[NULL]",$fix_str); 
    return "'".$fix_str."'"; 
} 
$query=mssql_query('update prod_cat set htmlbottom='.sql_escape(str_repeat('\'choose_cat ', 122000)).
    ' where ID=1'   );  

$query=mssql_query('select htmlbottom from prod_cat where ID=1');
$a=mssql_fetch_assoc($query);
echo strlen($a['htmlbottom']);
```

Comment: Can you show the *exact* table definition and the code you are using to fetch the data?

Comment: Stop using TEXT, use VARCHAR(MAX) (or probably NVARCHAR(MAX)). What do LEN(column) and DATALENGTH(column) return? Can you also show the code that adds data to the table? Using Management Studio to SELECT the data is not a valid test because by default the output is truncated (and can be configured to a higher amount, but not sufficient to show the entire contents of a TEXT column).

Comment: and what MSSQL extension are you using with PHP?

Comment: wasn't  VARCHAR(MAX) only 8 000 bytes??

Comment: @user1125062: no, starting in SQL Server 2005, a VARCHAR(MAX) column defined that way can store 2GB of data.

Comment: No, VARCHAR(MAX) is the replacement for TEXT, which is deprecated. It holds 2GB just like TEXT did, but is much easier to work with. [Plus it's not deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx).

Comment: Ah, maybe I should use it then... TEXT also seems to have problems with unpack, which I usually use for sanitizing..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft's PHP driver (for reference): http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

But if you don't want to (or can't) change drivers, from [this site](http://www.addedbytes.com/blog/sql-server-php-truncating-text/):

```
You need to increase the maximum size of a text column to be returned from
SQL Server by PHP. You can do this with a simple SQL query:
    SET TEXTSIZE 2147483647

Which you can run with the following PHP (best run just after you make a
connection).
    mssql_query("SET TEXTSIZE 2147483647");

A better way to work around the issue is to change the "textlimit" and
"textsize" settings within php.ini, like so:
    mssql.textlimit = 2147483647
    mssql.textsize = 2147483647
```

Your MSSQL driver is truncating the text.  If you can't change datatypes, drivers, etc., this should fix the issue for you.

Comment: You can also do this in the [freetds.conf](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/freetdsconf.htm) file which is read by the driver.

Comment: Thanks! That solved it, I set setting in PHP ini - didn't think it was that limited by default.