# how to Read 10000+ bytes[] of binary data from DataBase?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cakephp, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

I have one table that contains Company's Logo.... whenever I read small image like **4096 bytes** It works perfectly, but i am not able to read over the **10000 bytes** in php.
it's read only **4096 bytes** from database

**Update:**
Column Lenth in Sql :
[image]

**My Code in Model**

```
function GetLogoById($Id)
    {

        $this->load->database();
            mssql_query("SET TEXTSIZE 2147483647");

    // or use CI's active record
    $this->db->query("SET TEXTSIZE 2147483647");
        $query =  $this->db->query( "EXEC GetLogoById '$Id'" );
        $result = array();
        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        {
            $result[] = array("Logo"=> $row->Logo);
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

**My Controller Code :**

```
public function GetLogoById()
    {

        parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],$_GET);
        $Id = $_GET['Id'];
        $this->load->model('MyModel');
        $result = $this->MyModel->GetLogoById($Id);
        header('Content-type: image/png');
        echo  $result[0]['Logo'];   

    }
```

I am Getting Only 4096 bytes like :`(string:4096) ����`

I am getting this error on browser :
[image]

Comment: @PatrickEvans, actually same column & data another person are using on .NET ....and it's work fine...so, i dont think so, it's issue with data..for same column another record which have 4088 size it's work fine. but for column which are not coming on Php code which have 10000 size...i think, i have to increase php size limit. but HOW ...I dont know.

Comment: I M using MsSql. and my Data is Binary array of image. i am calling Data and show on url....code work fine for who have 3000 data size. not work more thn 10000 data size.

Comment: @PatrickEvans: i think issue is not, how many byte store on DB...issue is when retrieve from DB...nearest 4096 size data can catch on PHP code remain data not come up. so, how we can retrieve or increase php memory size.

Comment: @PatrickEvans : so What is the issue ?

Comment: @Jignesh.Raj, you say your column type for your logo is BINARY, from the sources i have seen BINARY can only hold at the max 8000 bytes, So if you try to store an image larger than 8 kilobytes into that field its going to truncate the data to 8000 bytes the rest gets lost. You and Kvadiyatar mention upping the PHP memory size but this would not matter as you are not getting an Exceeded Memory Limit error

Comment: @PatrickEvans : Plz See In my Update... in database has already contain 10000 + lenth

Comment: @Jignesh.Raj, hmm maybe the sources i read were of some other version mssql. will remove my other comments to clean up, Do not see what could be truncating the data then.

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: @PatrickEvans: It's Ok My Friend

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan: Cannot be displayed because it contains errors

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan: plz see in my question

Comment: A good practice is to not use database to store images, but only informations (Path, fileName, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got solution with `sqlsrv` driver ;)

```
 function GetLogoById($Id)
        {

            $serverName = "XXXXX";
            $uid = "XXXXXX";
            $pwd = "XXXXXX";

            $connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid,
                    "PWD"=>$pwd,
                    "Database"=>"XXXXXX");
            $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
            $tsql = "select Logo from TableName where Id = '$Id'";
            $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);
            if( $stmt === false)
            {
                echo "Error in query preparation/execution.\n";
                die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
            }
            /* Retrieve each row as an associative array and display the results.*/
            while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                return $row;
            }
            /* Free statement and connection resources. */
            sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
            sqlsrv_close( $conn);

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a problem with using MSSQL where data stored in a text type column is truncated for no apparent reason after 4096 characters.

Increase the maximum size of a text column to be returned from SQL Server. You can do this with the following SQL query:

```sql
SET TEXTSIZE 2147483647
```

You can run this with the following PHP, run it right after you make the connection:

```php
mssql_query("SET TEXTSIZE 2147483647");

// or use CI's active record
$this->db->query("SET TEXTSIZE 2147483647");
```

And another way way to work around the issue is to change the "textlimit" and "textsize" settings within php.ini, like the following:

```
mssql.textlimit = 2147483647
mssql.textsize = 2147483647
```

Refer to this SO answer [Why TEXT column returns only 4096 bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10904179/1893629) which refers to [SQL Server, PHP and Truncating Text](http://www.addedbytes.com/blog/sql-server-php-truncating-text/).

**Update:** Upon further review, reading [this PHP bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=38805), you may want to try using `PDO_ODBC` to connect to MSSQL Server instead:

```php
//$dsn = 'mssql:host=MYBOX;dbname=testdb'; 
$dsn = 'odbc:DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=MYBOX;DATABASE=testdb;';
```

Also try setting the `TEXTSIZE` to megabytes:

```php
$sql = "SET TEXTSIZE 3145728"; // 3 Megabytes
mssql_query($sql, $db) or die(mssql_get_last_message());
```

Comment: I tried both side php.ini and in php code but got only 4096 bytes

Comment: Have you downloaded this? http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

Comment: Hi I Got Success with my way actual that is a driver problem

Comment: So it was the Microsoft drivers?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38854/discussion-between-jignesh-raj-and-doitlikejustin)

Comment: Thanks for taking time for me 50+

Answer (score 0):

First. don't use the DBMS to store images. trust me.

Second, don't use the DMBS to store the images.....

Now, if you are getting an $id from the model, why have looping code to return an array? kind of defeats the purpose of an id?

I assume that the logo data is stored in the form of a BLOB ?

If this is the case the model could be something like:

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('tablename',array('id' => $id));
if ($query->num_rows() == 1)
{
    return $query->first_row()->logo
}
else
{
    return FALSE;
}
```

then the controller code could be something like:

```
  public function GetLogoById($id)
    {
        $this->load->model('MyModel');
        if($logo = $this->MyModel->GetLogoById($id))
        {
           $this->output->set_content_type('image/png');
           $this->output->set_output($logo);  
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for replay but  issue is same i am getting from database 4096 bytes

Comment: is there a reason you can't store the data as a BLOB?